# masking port number django runsslserver in nginx

Tags: django, ssl, nginx

I have django project running in ngnix in port 4321. i am runing django project using runsslserver which is returning me https
using below command

```
python manage.py runsslserver --certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/XXXXXXX.pem --key /etc/nginx/ssl/XXXXXXX.key 0.0.0.0:4321
```

my website is ready when i run like https://mywebsite.com:4321

I want to show it as https://mywebsite.com/miniweb

i have 2 files in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled which is default and ssl

Tried below code and few others with many changes in `ssl` file but not working

```
server {
server_name mywebsite.com:4321;
listen 443; # tried this because its in https
return 301 https://mywebsite.com/miniweb$request_uri;
}
```

Please help me

Comment: `runsslserver` is designed so you can use https in development. You shouldn't use it in production because it's not secure. Nginx + gunicorn or Nginx + uwsgi are two common ways to deploy Django. When you do this, `gunicorn` and `uwsgi` are not accessible to the public internet, and Nginx handles the SSL certificate.

Comment: There are a couple of issues with the config in your question: Remove `:4321` - you want nginx to listen on port 443. Don't use 301 - this redirects the browser to a new URL. Instead, you want to use [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) so that Nginx passes the request to your Django server. But as I said in my previous comment, that server should be `gunicorn` or `uwsgi` instead of `runsslserver`.